# Replacing Characters In C# String

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, replace

I am attempting to replace characters in a string data type.  Below is my code, but the `'` is not being replaced with `''`.  Am I mis-understanding how the `replace()` function operates?  What should I do in order to change the string to `High Flying Picture''s`?

This is the syntax I attempted.

```
public static void Test()
{
    string strVar = "High Flying Picture's";
    strVar.Replace("'", "''");
    Console.WriteLine(strVar);
}
```

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS!** Replacing the `'` character with two of them almost always has to do with a fix for strings that will be using in SQL statements, and this technique is **WRONG** and _WILL_ result in your code getting hacked. Instead, research parameterized queries.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I am using C# and the Microsoft Excel Interop to create hyperlinks from a Master Worksheet to Sub Worksheets.  Sometimes the Name in the Master Sheet (like High Flying Picture's) has an apostrophe in the name, and in order to properly create the hyperlink I need to double the apostrophe.  Since I am new to the world of C# - I will keep this in mind for when I am writing parameter queries.

Comment: I do not feel that the duplicate ? posed really is a duplicate of my question.  That question gives a great explanation of how to replace paths, but I was needing to replace a character in a string.  However, after seeing the answer from @JohanP - I see that the baseline is the same of me just needing to alter syntax to `strVar = strVar.Replace("'", "''");` so the basis is the same.  But for a new learner like myself, it would be difficult to follow IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strVar = strVar.Replace("'", "''");
```

You need to reassign it.